# Add Custom Filter to a field using linked entities using Javascript in Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have a field where I want to add a custom filter. This filter will be based on the value of a linked entity.

But, I found out that we cannot have complex queries using addCustomFilter() method.

What is the other way to do the same?

Comment: Show us what code you have tried, what you want to achieve..

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can have complex queries. Build the query using FetchXml. Ok here the JS I've used. I'll explain. I have a user lookup which I filter using a custom view based on the value selected in another lookup called areas.

Create the javascript function below in the form that you want this functionality.

fetchXml is where you create the query. As you can see, I'm querying the system user entity, then crossing over to the AreaUserLink entity (join on tes_user = systemuserid) and then filtering on the tes_area field = the value inserted from the form field.

layoutXml is where you define the layout of the screen that gets displayed when the person clicks on the lookup and goes to the lookup details screen. You will need to amend those to fit your new scenario.

viewId is just a random GUID that you need to provide so that CRM can store it. It will need to be unique.

In the code below...

```
function AttachReviewByCustomView() {
    var areaLookup = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('tes_area').getValue();
    if (areaLookup == null) {
        return;
    }

    var fetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>" +
        "<entity name='systemuser'><attribute name='fullname' /><attribute name='systemuserid' />" +
        "<order attribute='fullname' descending='false' />" +
        "<filter type='and'>" +
        "<condition attribute='isdisabled' value='0' operator='eq'/></filter>" +
        "<link-entity name='tes_userarealink' from='tes_user' to='systemuserid' alias='ak'>" +
        "<filter type='and'>" +
        "<condition attribute='tes_area' operator='eq' uitype='tes_area' value='" + areaLookup[0].id + "' />" +
        "</filter></link-entity></entity></fetch>";

    var layoutXml = "<grid name='resultset' object='1' jump='systemuserid' select='1' icon='1' preview='1'>" +
                    "<row name='result' id='systemuserid'>" +
                    "<cell name='fullname' width='150' />" +
                    "</row></grid>";

    var viewId = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003}";
    var viewDisplayName = "Active Users In Selected User-Area";
    Xrm.Page.getControl("tes_operative").addCustomView(viewId, "systemuser", viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, true);
}
```

Lastly you need to call this from two places. 
1. When the form loads.
2. When the person selects a value from the dropdown field that is used in the fetchXml variable to filter.

Hope this helps.